# Une meilleure nomenclature pour les temps grammaticaux

Tags: conjugaison, temps-grammatical, linguistique, mode-grammatical

Plusieurs questions sur ce site demandent des clarifications sur l'usage des temps et modes en français. Et j'en viens à la conclusion que la nomenclature traditionnelle des temps et modes en français est extrêmement trompeuse.

Ce qui suit est mon analyse des *aspects* et *temps réels* qui correspondent à chacune des formes verbales disponibles en français. Elle n'est pas forcément bonne ou parfaite, mais j'espère qu'elle donne une idée des reproches qu'on peut faire à la nomenclature traditionnelle. Je suis à la recherche d'une nomenclature nouvelle qui reflète ou ressemble à cette analyse (au moins en partie).

**Question :** Connaissez-vous des références bibliographiques ou des suggestions de réformes qui auraient déjà été proposées avec la même intention ?

J'ai pu trouver une description de toutes sortes d'aspects, plusieurs ont une transcription grammaticale dans d'autres langues, mais pour l'instant aucune analyse complète qui ferait correspondre certains aspects aux différentes conjugaisons qui existent en français. Référence wanted!

---

Les aspects que je considère sont les suivants :

- *Fait* : Une action qui commence et finit (la tâche n'est pas nécessairement initiée/entamée ou terminée/achevée pour autant).
- *Imparfait* : Un procédé en cours, habituel, ou une vérité générale.
- *Accompli* : Un action accomplie — déjà réalisée.
- *Révolu* : Un procédé révolu — qui a eu cours, qui a été habituel, ou a été vrai (plus précisément, l'état courant n'est ni important ni précisé).

<sup>(En réponse au commentaire d'Evpok : avec les termes trouvés sur la page [Aspect](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect) de Wikipédia, il semble que *fait* = inaccompli, non-sécant ; *imparfait* = inaccompli, sécant ; *accompli* = accompli, non-sécant ; et *révolu* = accompli, sécant. Cela semble confirmé par les passages « En français, les formes composées indiquent systématiquement un aspect accompli, et les formes simples un aspect inaccompli. » et « Le passé simple marqu[e] l'aspect non-sécant (global) et l'imparfait l'aspect sécant. » trouvés sur la page [Aspect grammatical](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_grammatical).)</sup>

Et les temps sont simplement le *passé* (utilisé pour le passé aussi bien que pour la narration), le *présent* et le *futur*. Pour certaines formes le temps est cependant *indéfini* ; il est généralement, dans ce cas, déduit du temps ou du sens d'un autre verbe de la phrase.

Le tableau décrit les associations suivantes pour chacune des formes verbales :

```
Nomenclature standard   Aspects possibles     Temps
```

Indicatif:

```
Futur simple            Fait ou Imparfait     Futur
Futur antérieur         Accompli ou Révolu    Futur

Présent                 Fait ou Imparfait     Présent
Passé composé           Accompli ou Révolu    Présent

Passé simple            Fait                  Passé
Passé antérieur         Accompli              Passé

Imparfait               Imparfait             Passé
Plus que parfait        Révolu                Passé
```

(Sauf dans les textes littéraires, le *passé simple* est remplacé par le *passé composé* et le *passé antérieur* par le *plus que parfait*.)

Subjonctif:

```
Présent                 Fait ou Imparfait     Présent ou Futur
Passé                   Accompli ou Révolu    Présent ou Futur

Imparfait               Fait ou Imparfait     Passé
Plus que parfait        Accompli ou Révolu    Passé
```

(Sauf dans les textes littéraires, les deux premières formes sont utilisées pour tous les temps.)

Conditionnel:

```
Présent                 Fait ou Imparfait     Présent ou Futur
Passé I                 Accompli ou Révolu    Présent ou Futur

Passé II                F. ou I. ou A. ou R.  Passé
```

(Sauf dans les textes littéraires le *passé deuxième forme* est remplacé par le *passé première forme*.)

Suivent les formes infinitives et participiales que je différencie cette fois selon voix active et voix passive. Certaines formes n'ont même pas de nom dans la nomenclature standard (et les cas particuliers des verbes qui utilisent l'auxiliaire *être* et des verbes pronominaux ne sont pas mentionnés).

Forme infinitive (voix active) :

```
Présent                 Fait ou Imparfait     Indéfini
Passée: avoir + P.Pa.   Accompli ou Révolu    Indéfini
```

Forme participiale (voix active) :

```
Présent                 Imparfait             Indéfini
ayant + P.Pa.           Révolu                Indéfini
```

Forme infinitive (voix passive) :

```
être + P.Pa.            Fait ou Imparfait     Indéfini
avoir été + P.Pa.       Accompli ou Révolu    Indéfini
```

Forme participiale (voix passive) :

```
(étant +) P.Pa.         Imparfait             Indéfini
(ayant été +) P.Pa.     Révolu                Indéfini
```

(Les auxiliaires dans les formes participiales sont souvent omis, ce qui crée parfois des ambiguïtés, mais elles sont généralement résolues grâce au contexte.)

---

On peut noter que l'aspect *continu* de l'anglais n'est pas exprimable directement en français, il correspond approximativement à une portion de l'*imparfait*, mais celui-ci n'est différencié en français que pour les formes du passé à l'indicatif.

Avec cette analyse, la correspondance des temps (et des aspects lorsque c'est nécessaire) devient plus facile.

Comment: Pour la nomenclature des aspects : on appelle en général *inaccompli* ce que tu appelles *imparfait*, et ton *Fait* et ton *Révolu* ne sont pas autre chose que des *Accompli* ne servant respectivement que pour les verbes d'action et d'état (ou les procès téliques et atéliques) si je te comprends bien.

Comment: Ah, merci pour la terminologie, mais je conçois ce  « révolu » comme quelque chose typiquement « imparfait » qui est « accompli/fini/terminé » (par exemple: *jusque-là les puissants avaient écrit la loi*), ça deviendrait donc avec les termes proposés un « *inaccomplissement accompli* »… je veux bien, mais c'est quelque peu oxymorique.

Comment: Non, c'est bien un inaccompli, mais du passé. Un verbe a un temps, un mode et un aspect. Tu oublie le temps dans ton analyse. L'imparfait en français c'est pour un procès qui est inaccompli à l'époque de la narration, cette époque étant antérieure à celle de l'énonciation. Il n'implique d'ailleurs pas que le procès est effectivement accompli au moment de la narration, si « je mangeais quand il est arrivé », je peux très bien être encore en train de manger.

Comment: Pour moi qui suis béotien et d'après mon expérience de l'apprentissage de l'anglais, j'ai l'impression que la difficulté vient moins de la nomenclature elle-même que de la différence de conception des temps et des modes entre les langues romanes et les langues anglo-saxonnes. Mes amis Italiens n'ont pas de difficulté sur ce sujet.

Comment: @mouviciel: Le fonctionnement des temps dans les autres langues romanes étant similaire, ils savent déjà les utiliser sans avoir besoin d'explications. J'ai regardé du côté des nomenclatures espagnole et italienne, par comparaison avec le français il y a peut-être du mieux, mais ce n'est pas transcendant (et je ne sais pas si les usages correspondent parfaitement).

Comment: Le présent peut être utilisé pour parler de l'avenir: je prends l'avion demain.

Comment: En effet, la nomenclature est trompeuse. Par exemple, de point de vue de l'anglais, *imparfait* est vrament un temps continu (*past continuous tense*) alors que *passé composé* est un temps *parfait*, mais pas forcement *passé*, car il peut se traduire (le plus souvent) soit par *present perfect*, soit par *past perfect* - dependamment de la relation d'action au moment present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voici une référence: Le Français déchiffré Clé du langage et des langues
Dossier 5: La géométrie des temps et des modes.

Comment: Serait-il possible d'expliquer rapidement de quoi il retourne, en quoi cette référence pourrait être utile pour une possible recatégorisation des conjugaisons ?

Comment: Voir Henri Adamczewski sur Wikipédia.

Comment: Conclusion dossier 5: 'La tradition nous a légué un très (trop) grand nombre de formes baptisées "temps". Le résultat est que le chapitre des temps est sans doute celui qui présente l'image la plus chaotique dans les grammaires (ce qui rend le passage d'une langue à l'autre pratiquement impossible).Une meilleure compréhension des phénomènes temporels (avec une définition stricte des temps grammaticaux) et surtout une redéfinition de l'aspect et de la modalité nous ont permis de mettre un peu d'ordre dans un tableau déroutant.'

Comment: Le livre donné en référence donne seulement des pistes pour donner envie de mettre au point et d'écrire une grammaire métaopérationnelle du français, comme cela a été fait pour l'anglais par l'auteur. La lecture de 'Grammaire expliquée de l'anglais' de Jean-Pierre Gabilan,(ellipse) montre bien la simplicité des mécanismes mis à jour et cela sans le moindre jargon.

Comment: J'avais raté les trois derniers commentaires. Ça m'a tout à fait l'air d'être pertinent. Je vais essayer de mettre la main dessus. En attendant comme il n'y a pas d'autre réponse, je valide ça comme la meilleure piste.

Answer (score 1):

Pour des références bibliographiques classiques :

Confais, J. P. (2002). Temps, mode, aspect: les approches des morphèmes verbaux et leurs problèmes à l'exemple du français et de l'allemand. Presses Univ. du Mirail.

Gosselin, L. (1996). Sémantique de la temporalité en français: un modèle calculatoire et cognitif du temps et de l'aspect. Duculot.

Imbs, P. (1960). L'emploi des temps verbaux en français moderne (Vol. 1). C. Klincksieck.

Touratier, C. (1996). Le système verbal français: description morphologique et morphématique. A. Colin.

Vet, C. (1980). Temps, aspects et adverbes de temps en français contemporain (Vol. 154). Amsterdam.