# Existe-t-il une 3e forme du conditionnel?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, mode-grammatical

Je suis en train de programmer un algorithme pour conjuguer les verbes français. J'ai créé une petite liste des temps de verbes, mais je crois qu'il y a un problème : [ce site](http://www.conjugation-fr.com/conjugate.php?verb=avoir&x=0&y=0) me dit qu'il y a un « *Conditional Second Past* », qui est construit par :

sujet + auxiliaire (*conjugué au subjonctif imparfait*) + participe passé du verbe

> Première personne au singulier :
>
> Je + avoir (*eusse*) + eu = **j'eusse eu**

Mais effectivement c'est le *plus-que-parfait du subjonctif* (sans le 'que'). Donc je me demande si c'est une faute du site, ou si ça existe vraiment et que je ne l'ai pas trouvé dans mes livres de grammaire. Cette forme n'est pas dans le [Bescherelle](http://www.bescherelle.com/index.php) non plus.

J'ai lu [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/une-meilleure-nomenclature-pour-les-temps-grammaticaux?rq=1), et il me semble que le « Passé II » du conditionnel soit une forme littéraire. Peut-être que ce n'est pas encore utilisé, je n'en suis pas sûr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il existe bel et bien une 3e forme du conditionnel. Le conditionnel passé deuxième forme (identique au subjonctif plus-que-parfait) est une variante littéraire et soutenue de la première forme.

Vous pouvez le voir sur le site web suivant:
http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/avoir.html

Veuillez toutefois prendre note que la majorité des gens rejettent aujourd'hui cette appellation, puisqu'elle prête inutilement à confusion.